flask-sqlalchemy bind not being acknowledged by app
I have an app using Flask 3.0.3, Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.1.1, SQLAlchemy 2.0.31 and Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS that was recently updated. When I try to edit an item, I get the error, (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1142, "UPDATE command denied to user 'read_only'@'localhost' for table 'ads'").
How do I get the new versions to properly read the binds?
config.cfg
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://read_only:12345@localhost:3306/mysql_bind_test'

SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
        "readAndWrite": "mysql://editing_user:12345@localhost:3306/mysql_bind_test",
    } 

Ads.py
class AdModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ads'

    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    hidden = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    title = db.Column(db.Text, default="")

class AdModelWrite(AdModel):
    __tablename__ = 'ads'
    __bind_key__ = 'readAndWrite'

    def save_to_db(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

I have tried changing the binds to the new dictionary format below, tried adding the bind programmatically in the app setup, and setting the bind explicitly in the save_to_db() function in the class.
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    "readAndWrite": {
        "url": "mysql://editing_user:12345@localhost:3306/mysql_bind_test",
        "pool_recycle": 3600
        }
    } 

I know the database is accessible because the editing will occur if the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI is set to the 'readAndWrite' url.

If you separate your model so that your AdModelWrite doesn't inherit from AdModel what happens? Your error reads like the it's executing with the default engine, I'm wondering if the way the binds are initialized, you're not actually overwriting the bind key with your inheritance structure.

@president-james-k-polk, I tried your suggestion. It works for the limited use of my example (which is truncated), but not practical for the real app. (Maintaining 2 large classes and not using inheritance is problematic). I went to the documentation for flask-sqlalchemy 3.x and found references to Mapped for configuration... That did not work either.
